# Can I use react suspense in production?

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

In this [page](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy), they use `Suspense` with `React.lazy` for lazily loading components. However, `Suspense` itself is listed under the experimental `Conccurrent mode` which is not stable yet as they note [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html). I don't understand. Can I use `Suspense` in production ?

Comment: I don't understand the confusion - you found the clear statement saying not to?

Comment: Well, they mention you can not use `React.lazy` without `Suspense`. However, It's fine to use React.lazy in production. That's nonsense. Also, There are many libraries that make use of `Suspense` such as 'reacti18next`.

Comment: Sounds like you have your answer already then.

Comment: Then, why do react docs mention that it's experimental and should not be used in production ?

Comment: You'd have to ask the person who wrote them...